# Open Source dialog directly by clicking custom button

Tags: ckeditor

I use CKEDITOR and need to open Source Dialog only, without toolbar and button Source. I want to click button in separate place and show dialog to user. Searching in docs doesnt give any result. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: So, is there a CKEditor instance present or do you want it to appear after clicking this button?

Comment: there isnt. i need to create dialog after clicking on the button with ckeditor instance in the background.

Comment: This could help you: https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/sourcedialog If you install it, you could call its command using an external button's click event like this (assuming an instance named `editor1`) : `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.execCommand('sourcedialog')`

Comment: Figured out, thank you